# more than you have had dinners

Tags: comparative-constructions

a. He has read more books than you have had dinners.

Meaning: The numbers of the books he has read is greater than the number of dinners you have had.

Is (a) grammatically correct?

It is supposed to be a hyperbolic statement of course. It's very probably not literally true.

Comment: Yes it's idiomatic and most unlikely to be literally true.

Answer (score 2):

Usually  "... than you've had hot dinners".  It is a hyperbolic expression, used to express the idea of "[a very large number](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+than+has+had+hot+dinners)". So in the example it means

> He has read a lot of books.

But it is rather clichéd. It is humorous, but now the joke might be more parody.  It is also notably British.

Answer (score 2):

This is grammatically correct.

The meaning is slightly different to what you have written. Although this made simply be a typo on your part.

It would mean:
The numbers of the books *he has* read is greater than the number of dinners you have had

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

In England, where I’m from, it is often said colloquially as “hot dinners” rather than just “dinners”.

It’s also somewhat “made” by a casual/abbreviated tone of voice, and would be said like:

> He’s read more books than you’ve had hot dinners!